# Does $x^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ mean $x$ and $n$ are coprime?

Tags: number-theory

I'm really bad at number theory. Need someone to check my proof.

Assume the opposite: $x$ and $n$ have a common prime factor $p$. Then $n = ps$ and $sx^{n-1}=s(p^{n-1}r^{n-1})=(sp)l=nl\equiv0 \pmod n$. Given that $x^{n-1}\equiv1 \pmod n$, this would mean $s\equiv0 \pmod n$ and thus $n = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Will that do? Or am I missing something and this one is incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: That looks fine to me...

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is fine. Here's another. By definition of congruence there's $s$ such that $x x^{n-2} = 1 + s n$, or $x x^{n-2} - s n = 1$, from which you see that $x$ and $n$ are coprime.

(This works for $n > 1$, for $n = 1$ the statement is clearly true.)